# how do i build a N-day retention chart in postgres?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I want to build a D0 - D30, N-day retention chart for all users who join and perform at least 1 out of 2 core actions (added a picture or viewed a picture).

```
So for example, user 1 and 2 both join on 2022-10-01 (day 0)
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* user 1 views a picture (day 0)        |  * user 2 adds a picture (day 0)
* user 1 adds a picture (day 1)         |  * user 2 add a picture (day 1)
* user 1 does nothing (day 2)           |  * user 2 views a picture (day 2)     
* user 1 views a picture (day 3)        |  * user 2 adds and views multiple pictures (day 3)
* user 1 does nothing (day 4)           |  * user 2 does nothing (day 4)
```

The retention chart looks like the following:

```
date_joined | # of users |  D0  |  D1  |  D2  |  D3  |  D4 | ... | D30
----------------------------------------------------------------------
2022-10-01  |      2     | 100% | 100% |  50% | 100% |  0% | ... | X%
```

- D2 is 50% since user 1 did nothing, and user 2 viewed a pic (1 out of 2 people performed core actions)
- D4 is 0% since both users did nothing

### The following tables are needed:

user table

```
-----------------
id | join_date 
-----------------
 1 | 2022-10-01
 2 | 2022-10-01
```

picture table

```
id |      timestamp      | userId |     url
-------------------------------------------------
1  | 2022-10-01 10:00:00 |    2   | http://www...
2  | 2022-10-02 08:00:00 |    1   | http://www...
3  | 2022-10-02 09:00:00 |    2   | http://www...
4  | 2022-10-04 05:00:00 |    2   | http://www...
5  | 2022-10-04 06:00:00 |    2   | http://www...
```

view table

```
id |      timestamp      | userId 
----------------------------------
1  | 2022-10-01 11:00:00 |   1
2  | 2022-10-03 07:00:00 |   2
3  | 2022-10-04 09:00:00 |   1
4  | 2022-10-04 10:00:00 |   2
5  | 2022-10-04 11:00:00 |   2
```

### What I have tried so far:

- I can get a daily breakdown of users who have performed a core action, but don't know how to track them over 30 days, and do this for each day a user has joined.

What I have:

```
date       | # users who performed core action
-----------------------------------------
2022-10-01 | 100
2022-10-02 | 59
2022-10-03 | 129
2022-10-04 | 143
```

The reason this is not close to what I need is that, for each day I get the TOTAL number of users who have peformed the core actions, not just actions performed by users who have joined on X date.

I.e: 2022-10-01 shows me all users in the plaftorm who have performed at least 1 out of 2 core actions.

I need to track users who joined on 2022-10-01 for 30 days, users who joined on 2022-10-02 for 30 days, etc.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution to your request is not obvious.

Starting with the look of your retention chart with 30 columns with labels from "D1" to "D30", we are going to create a dedicated composite type with the corresponding labels with "d" lower case instead of "D" upper case because postgres automatically converts column labels into lower case :

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE composite_type() LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$
DECLARE
  txt text ;
BEGIN
  SELECT string_agg('d' || i || ' text',',') INTO txt
    FROM generate_series(1,30) AS i ;
  DROP TYPE IF EXISTS composite_type ;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TYPE composite_type AS (' || txt || ')' ;
END ; $$ ;
CALL composite_type() ;
```

Then we have a quite complex query which does the job :

```
WITH list AS (
SELECT u.join_date AS date_joined
     , 'd' || d.id AS date_label
     , array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT u.id), 1) AS "# of users"
     , to_char(COALESCE(array_length(array_remove(array_agg(DISTINCT COALESCE(p.userId, v.userId)), NULL), 1)
     / array_length(array_agg(DISTINCT u.id), 1) :: numeric * 100, 0), '999') || '%' AS ratio
  FROM "user" AS u
 CROSS JOIN LATERAL generate_series (u.join_date, u.join_date + interval '30 days', interval '1 day') WITH ORDINALITY AS d(day, id)
  LEFT JOIN "picture" AS p ON p.userId = u.id AND p.timestamp :: date = d.day
  LEFT JOIN "view" AS v ON v.userId = u.id AND v.timestamp :: date = d.day
 GROUP BY u.join_date, d.id
)
SELECT date_joined, "# of users"
     , (jsonb_populate_record(NULL :: composite_type, jsonb_object_agg(date_label, ratio))).*
  FROM list
 GROUP BY date_joined, "# of users"
```

In the CTE part of the query :

- The query starts from the table `user` by grouping the users by `date_joined`.
- Then it cross-joins with the 30 days following the `date_joined` and whose list is automatically generated by the function `generate_series()`.
- Then it left-joins with the `picture` and the `view` tables. The left join allows to identify the days where no user from the group of users did an action.
- Then it aggregates the users in an array per date_joined and per following dates with a DISTINCT clause so that to not double count the same user who performed several actions at the same date.
- Then it removes the NULL values from the array and it calculates the length of the array which corresponds to the number of active users at that date.
- This number of active useres is divided by the total number of users grouped by `date_joined` and it is formatted as a percentage.

The last part of the query retrieve all the rows from the CTE and display the expected result by using the `jsonb_populate_record()` and the `composite_type` so that to display the columns "d1" ... "d30" and the corresponding values.

The result is :

| date_joined | # of users | d1 | d2 | d3 | d4 | d5 | d6 | d7 | d8 | d9 | d10 | d11 | d12 | d13 | d14 | d15 | d16 | d17 | d18 | d19 | d20 | d21 | d22 | d23 | d24 | d25 | d26 | d27 | d28 | d29 | d30 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-10-01 | 2 | 100% | 100% | 50% | 100% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% | 0% |

see the test result in [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/DX8F25lj)

Comment: Thanks @Edouard for the concise solution and in-depth explanation! I was able to modify the query to start the chart at "d0" and as a follow up, based on a selected date, modify the query to also give me a breakdown of the retention of inidivudal users that joined on a specifc date! The only thing I noticed was the query performance, since it took ~14 sec to compute. Is there anything that can be done to make it more performant?

Comment: Not easy to predict the performance of such a query. First of all, it seems that the query is going to scan the full table `"user"` because there is no filter condition on it, so any index will be useless here. Then, for each row retrieved from this table, it would be interesting to check if the `LEFT JOIN` on tables `"picture"`and `"view"`are relying on an index. You can execute your query with `EXPLAIN ANALYSE` and share the result in your updated question to have a look.